# what are the differences between wire and tri nets, wand and triand with examples?

Tags: verilog

I'm learning Verilog. I'm not understanding the differences between wire & tri net types, wand & triand net types. Where exactly we need to specify a net as wand and as a triand?

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between `wire` and `tri`. They are synonyms. Usually the convention is to use `wire` in regular declaration and `tri` in declaration of multiple-driven **nets** and `inout` ports. Same is true for `wand`/`triand`, `wor`/`trior`. However there are more variation of `tri`, like `tri1`, `tri0`. There is also a tri-state register type: `trireg`.

For practical purposes only `wire` and `tri` are synthesizable, the rest are not.

The difference between the regular wire/tri types and their and/or versions is in the resulting value resolution where the net is driven by multiple drivers. For simple `wire` when it is driven by several signals with different values, the result will be **X**. Otherwise it will have the value of all drivers. The `and` version will do **&** between them, the `or` will do **|**.

Here are the truth tables for the three net types driven by 2 driver:

wire/tri

```
  0 1 x z
0 0 x x 0
1 x 1 x 1
x x x x x
z 0 1 x z
```

wand/triand

```
  0 1 x z
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 x 1
x 0 x x x
z 0 1 x z
```

wor/trior

```
  0 1 x z
0 0 1 x 0
1 1 1 1 1
x x 1 x x
z 0 1 x z
```